# How to render a page with a GridCommand action in a MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller, ext.net

I have a grid direct command with a url redirect and some parameter.
This is the portion of code into the caller cshtml file:

```
    .Commands(
     Html.X().GridCommand()
     .CommandName("Edit")
     .Icon(Icon.NoteEdit)
     .ToolTip(t =>
    {
     t.Text = "Modifica della ripartizione ferie per giorno";
    })
    )
   .ID("EDITID1")
   .DirectEvents(
      directEvents =>
      {
      directEvents.Command.Url = "/PianoFerieOreMese";
      directEvents.Command.Action = ""; 
      directEvents.Command.ExtraParams.Add(
      ...
```

Both the controller file and cshtml file of the redirected are processed correcly, but the csthml file will not be rendered into the browser.
Why? How do I have to do in order to perform display?

------------- SECOND STEP
Maybe I have found the problem.
I have to use Listener instead of CommandDirect Events.
Can someone help me to do some step ahead from
**.Listeners(ls => ls.Command.Handler = "Ext.Msg.alert(command, record.data.company);"**)
Instead of :
**Ext.Msg.alert(command, record.data.company);**
I have to create a custom JavaScript method that accept two parameters from record.data.

Comment: I'm in need of a urgent suggestion

Comment: There is a [related discussion](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?45071) on the Ext.NET forums.